# Android Start Service on run?

Tags: android, android-activity

what is the best way to implements a service from starting with alarm manager when android applications first starts? 
Right now i have a Home activity which is the first page of the activity which runs the service when it is being created. However when the users were to start the application again on the app menu (when the application is running.), the home activity will be run again and the service will start again.

Is there any better alternative for this way of application?

Comment: This question isn't clear.  Please elaborate about what you're trying to do.  Regardless, it sounds like you want to use bindService() and just override your onCreate() or onStartCommand() methods to not start if the service already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this link... have a look at the implemenation below.

http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/82 ...

and for the checking whether a service is active or not... you can simply use this.

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("com.example.background.BootableService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Use this in the any class you want to check for a existing service... and if no service is present then just create one or else you are good.

Let me know how it works out.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was talking about as far as a "check if this service is running" bit.  You could even make it nicer and include it in the constructor of the service, and return a null if the service is already running.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote... I have been struggling to get my rep up from quite some time... Thanks once again.

Comment: just keep at it.  this is a pretty inclusive community, most of us are friendly :)